# Offline Desktop Web Application with Python and Angular (or Django or something else)

Tags: python, django, angular, desktop-application, offline

**My background:**

I am just starting to learn backend development with only 1 `django` backend created and deployed. I have solid experience with game development, architectures, algorithms, and various technologies and languages.

**The Setup:**

I have a `python` script (call it the `solver`), which runs a complex calculation of some data. I **cannot** modify the calculation script; I can only modify the way they are called. Currently it works by typing `solver.py "params"` in a terminal, which returns the calculation results in a file. I have modified this to work by calling a method `execute()` which returns the solution as string (or a `json`/`yaml` object).

**The Task:**

I need to create a very simple desktop **offline** application to call the `solver` and output the solution. The `OS` is unknown at this stage (possibly `Windows`). There should be no requests to a remote server whatsoever (otherwise it would be a simple task) and the application should be run from a single file (e.g. `solver.exe`).

**Thoughts and Questions:**

1. My first thought was to create a simple `django`/`flask` local server and an `Angular` frontend. I know building `angular` apps with `electron` is simple, but I have no idea how to include the `django`/`flask` local server, how to create one locally for that matter and how to bundle them together. If you believe this is the simplest way, could you point me to some tutorial/video/library/framework that I could follow or use?
2. Second thought was to just create everything with `django`, which also has frontend capabilities. In this case, are there any packages, that would help me build the application offline and for desktop?
3. Third thought (I would love it if this was possible) is to just create an `Angular` application, which calls the `execute()` method (or runs the file with parameters) and to build it with `electron`. If this was possible, I could build the application in a day, which would make the customer very happy. From my research, I couldn't find a way to make this work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Creating the application with electron should be doable. You could pack the python script with it and execute it when needed. I believe you would need to have python installed though. Not sure why you would still need django/flask in this scenario.

Comment: Just to let you know, as per Agash Thamo. 's suggestion, I installed [ngx-childprocess](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-childprocess) instead of ngx-electron. Executing a file is working nicely with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you already look into [ngx-electron](https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron/)?
You can access electron through angular and then call a [ChildProcess](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) on NodeJS to [spawn/execute](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) your command.

Include your script into the bundle, call it from the command using the information provided in the links above.

Comment: Thank your comment. I believe that the user should have python installed in this case, right?  Maybe I can build a windows executable of the solver and use node to call it with parameters (as per your idea)! Would that work?

Comment: Yes the user need to have python installed in this case, as you execute it like you would in the command line `python solver.py "params"`.

Comment: On a side note, if the target computer is macOS, python is preinstalled. If it is Windows, you could use py2exe (http://www.py2exe.org/) and compile it to an executable you can use as is without the need of python installed on the target computer.